# What is Vcl.Bind.DBEngExt

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, firedac

What is Vcl.Bind.DBEngExt and why is it being added to the uses statement in my Data Module in a Fire Monkey application?

As far as I can tell I don't have any VCL components in that unit, nor anyplace in the application.

As a result whenever I build the application targeting Android or IOS Vcl.Bind.DBEngExt is being flagged as undefined.

There is a Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt in the uses statement that is defined but the VCL one still keeps getting automatically added.

Gary

Comment: Have a look at the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/ClassGroup_pseudo-property_of_TDataModule

Comment: Actually I hadn't noticed that property.  I had made other changes and go around the problem but I set this property anyway.  Thanks.